# kinetic js speed with many objects

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have a little html canvas app where I use kinetic js to animate a couple hundred small circles moving along individual lines. It works ok, but sometimes can be a little slow. I'd like to be able to scale it up to a few thousand, and have it update each circle on each frame. How can I make it faster? Are there better alternatives to kinetic js for this purpose? Thanks.

here's a sample:
http://www.cs.middlebury.edu/~gkrathwohl/running/ncaa.html

Comment: Can't tell what's going on in that page. The script seems to be obfuscated somehow. Can you post a jsfiddle? My initial question is how you're doing your main game loop. One of my early mistakes was allowing the movement to be based on the framerate not on the amount of time that had passed since the last run of the main loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not having the user interact with your runner circles.

Since you don't need interactivity provided by Kinetic.Circles, you can gain magnitudes of speed improvement by drawing all your runners on 1 single Kinetic.Shape instead of creating hundreds (thousands) of individual Kinetic.Circles.

The Kinetic.Shape gives you a context on which you can much more quickly draw non-interactive circles using native context.arc(x,y,radius,0,PI2).

If you later need interactivity, you can quickly test the mouse position vs each runner object mathematically.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for. For anyone still interested, I made a small fiddle where you can make lots of dots spread out in many directions. http://jsfiddle.net/QmbB9/ I'll try to make them all in the same Kinetic.Shape now.

Comment: Actually could you elaborate a little more on this? I don't need interactivity, but I still need each circle to follow it's own path at it's own pace. Here's a simple fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/QmbB9/ . In the actual project, each kinetic.circle keeps track of the path it's following and it's pace.

Comment: Got it. So the circles aren't objects anymore. In the animation, you totally redraw all of the circles (using setDrawFunc), based on a corresponding runner object. This makes it pretty smooth up to a few thousand. Maybe asking for 10, 20 thousand is too much.

Comment: Exactly, each runner is an object that's drawn using context.arc.  The actual objects depend on your design needs. For example, the runner object could have info like currentX, currentY, leg1time, leg2time, etc.  Then you could have an elapsedTime variable that times the race.  To get the runners current XY: first determine which leg the runner's on at that elapsedTime. Then calculate how far the runner has progressed on that leg as a percentage. Then interpolate the appropriate XY along that curve at that percentage.